# How to connect via udp in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I'm having trouble connecting via udp gstreamer python. When I enter the command `gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=3000 buffer-size=13000000 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! d3dvideosink sync=false`. Everything works, but when I try to connect via python "Could not open video"

```
import sys
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("udpsrc port=3000 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer mode=1 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink", cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER);

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Could not open video")
    sys.exit()

# Read first frame.
ok, frame = cap.read()
if not ok:
    print('Cannot read video file')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: "an error occurs" - what's the error? Please post the full error message

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the whole Error message, please?